# Use kendo ui grid, with data that properties starts with '@'

Tags: json, xml, kendo-ui

I have i transformed a XML to json, so the json file has symbol '@' in front of attributes. For example `<xml id=1></xml>` and i get { @id=1 }.

With this structure i have create some data, for example

```
[{@action:"include", @defaultValue:"", @expression:"", @format:"",@isPrimary:"True"},{@action:"include", @defaultValue:"", @expression:"", @format:"",@isPrimary:"True"},{@action:"include", @defaultValue:"", @expression:"", @format:"",@isPrimary:"True"}]
```

Now i want to implemented this with kendo grid, but i am little comfused.

```
   model: {
                fields: {
                    Action: {
                        field: '@action',
                    },
                    DefaultValue: {
                        field: '@defaultValue',
                    },
                    Format: {
                        field: '@format',
                    },
                    Expression: {
                        field: '@expression',
                    }
                }
            }
```

and in my columns

```
   columns: [{
        field: "Action",
        title: "Action",
    }, {
        field: "DefaultValue",
        title: "Default Value",
    }, {
        field: "Format",
        title: "Format",
    }, {
        field: "Expression",
        title: "Expression",
    }]
```

but doen't work, i get "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Answer (score 1):

1. your model definition is not valid syntax...the model.fields configuration does not seem to have fieldName.field option(http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#methods-Model.define).
2. "@" is really not a valid character in javascript names unless you put quotes around it, which you can easily do with the code you control like your data array literal...but kendo isn't doing that so it ends up trying to reference things like`d.@action`, which is a syntax error.  So, you have to "fool" kendo into using square-bracket notation AND quoted field name by using formatting like so:

   "['@action']"

when defining the field options.  This gives you a quoted field name to allow the @ and it causes kendo to use bracket notation instead of dot notation when accessing the fields

Here's a demo of it working: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/uPiGE

It demonstrates both the required formatting of the field names and the syntax of the model definition.

But, having said all that.....do you really need @ in your field names?

Comment: thanks for your response. to answer your question yes i need '@' because i get the data after transformation from XML to json. I saw your dojo and seems your solution works, but i find an other way, more simply...i just edit the data and delete the character '@' from attributes before initialize grid.

Comment: Yes, not using @ field names in your grid configuration is a solution...